# Erlang importing modules from other directories

Tags: import, module, erlang

I've done a module "parser" wich is located in "./local/lib/parser.erl". Is it possible to import the module from "./local/main.erl"?

I have tried to use in my main module:

-import("./lib/parser", [functions]).

-import('./lib/parser', [functions]).

-import(lib.parser, [functions]).

And none of them is giving to me the correct compilation. I have searched in Erlang's documentation but could not found what I was looking for.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> -import(Module,Functions). Imported functions. Can be called the same way as local functions, that is, without any module prefix.
>
> Module, an atom, specifies which module to import functions from.
>   Functions is a list similar as for export.

Your erlang source file in `./local/lib/parser.erl`, but after you compile this source file, there will be a `beam` file, your should add the `beam` file path to your `erlang code path`.

The right synax is `-import('parser', [functions]).`
But the path of `parse.beam` shoud be in your erlang code path.

About `erlang code path`, please read this link:http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html